# how to fetch props data within double quotes in rectjs

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to fetch data from a literature-based database called [Dimensions](https://badge.dimensions.ai/#build)

```
export default function PubItems({
  title = "This is title",
  authors = "this is the author list",
  journaL = "this is the journal name",
  issue = "This is the issue number",
  date = "This is publication date",
  doi,
  dbdoi,
  impact = "0.00",
}) {
  return (
    <PubItemsStyles>
      <div className="pubItems_info">
        <h3>
          {
            <a className="pubtitle" href={doi} target="__blank">
              {title}
            </a>
          }
        </h3>

        <p className="authors">{authors}</p>
        <p className="journal">
          <span className="jName">{journaL}</span>
          <span className="jIssue">{issue}</span>
          <span className="jIssue">{impact}</span>
        </p>
        <p className="date">{date}</p>

        <div className="metrics">
          <div>
            {
              <a className="doi" href={doi} target="__blank">
                Read Article
              </a>
            }
          </div>
          <span
            class="__dimensions_badge_embed__"
            data-doi="{bddoi}"
            data-style="large_rectangle"
          ></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </PubItemsStyles>
  );
```

here in the span data_doi comes from the Dimension badge async script, but i'm trying to fetch the doi number data from my props dbdoi. But in the double quotes, the prop not rendered. Also, without the double quotes the badge is not showing.

Comment: I am not sure, but is it a spelling mistake ? The variable you are trying to print and the one extracted from props are different

Comment: Thank you @SatwinderSingh for this concern. I've also tried with the correct spelling according to the props but it;s still not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the `dbdoi` prop passed to the component, the correct syntax should be:

```
<span
  class="__dimensions_badge_embed__"
  data-doi={dbdoi}
  data-style="large_rectangle"
></span>
```

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-z2xjvj?file=src/App.js